# How to render Vue's dynamic component tag with createElement?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is it possible to output Vue's special dynamic component tag `<component></component>` with the render function?

I am trying to recreate this template:

```
<template>
  <component :is="selectedComponent" @changeComponent="swap"></component>
</template>
```

with a render function like this:

```
  render(h) {
    return h('component', {
      props: {
        is: this.selectedComponent
      },
      on: {
        changeComponent: this.swap
      }
    })
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How about `h(this.selectedComponent, ...`?

Comment: @Phil ahhh that did it. I'm embarrassed I didn't think of that. I also removed the `is` prop and it seemed to work just fine too.